# Ajax Control Toolkit AsyncFileUploader Control and viewstate/session Issue

Tags: asp.net, session, ajaxcontroltoolkit, viewstate, asyncfileupload

in my project i need to upload files so i decided to use the uploader provided by asp.net ajax controls **AsyncFileUPloader** control.
there are four blocks. every block contains two such uploaders 
so i decided to utilize the power of asp.net web user controls.
i wrapped the required form fields in my user control called DesignUploader.ascx
now i have to put the four instances of this control on my aspx page 
please refer the snap below

[image]

my problem starts here i have to insert the fileurl to the database and each of the block generates unique id and id value changes after uploading the file to the server. i noticed that viewstate does not work for me in case of `asyncfileuploader` it clears the viewstate because it does the secret postback to the server behind the scenes. now only option left for me is to use **session**  but when user uploads the files in two blocks one after another then filepath from second/third consecutive blocks overwrite my session. i don't know how many blocks user can use to upload the designs he may use 1 only or he may use all four.

There would be a final submit button in the bottom of the page on click of which i have to insert data to database.

> so when i tried to save the data to database the session stores the value of the recently uploaded file path for all the records my problem lies here

i don't know if i was able to describe my problem in correct manner or not please excuse me if it is not clear and post comment if required.

Note: I can not change the UI because client insists for this only :(

any quick work around would be appreciated much

Thanks
Devjosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you saving file path to session in a wrong way and it's impossible to recognize where is an error without code.
All the way, in my opinion better don't persist file path in session but use client side for that purpose instead. You can add two hidden fields to DesignUploader.ascx control and set their values in `UploadedComplete` event handler.

```
public partial class DesignUploader : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private static readonly string AppDataPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");

    public string FirstFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.UrlDecode( FirstFilePathHiddenField.Value);
        }
    }

    public string SecondFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.UrlDecode(SecondFilePathHiddenField.Value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        FirstFileUpload.UploadedComplete += FirstFileUpload_UploadedComplete;
        SecondileUpload.UploadedComplete += SecondileUpload_UploadedComplete;
    }

    void FirstFileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(AppDataPath, Path.GetFileName(e.FileName));
        FirstFileUpload.SaveAs(fullPath);
        SaveFilePathToHiddenField(FirstFilePathHiddenField.ClientID, fullPath);
    }

    void SecondileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(AppDataPath, Path.GetFileName(e.FileName));
        SecondileUpload.SaveAs(fullPath);
        SaveFilePathToHiddenField(SecondFilePathHiddenField.ClientID, fullPath);
    }

    private void SaveFilePathToHiddenField(string fieldId, string pathValue)
    {
        var script = string.Format("top.$get('{0}').value = '{1}';", fieldId, Server.UrlEncode(pathValue));
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "setPath", script, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering.
yes as you said i tried that way of storing the filepath onfileuploaded event but when i set the hidden field in my server side onFileUploaded event the hiddenfield does not update/set  and thats why i used session to store as an alternative
right now i can not post code as i am out of my workplace. as you raised a custom event i have not tried that way.i will give it a try and let you know

Comment: There are no custom events in my code. You can't set hidden field value in `UploadedComplete` event handler as it executed asynchronously. But you can register javascript in it to update hidden field value on a client.  This is the case used in proposed code. Draw your attention that as AsyncFileUpload executed in frame you must to call `$get` function in parent frame.